# almost sure convergence and convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given $X_n=a_n|X|\mathbb{1}_{Z\leq b_n}$, where $1$ is the indicator function. $X$ is normally distributed and $Z$ is independent of $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive numbers where $b_n\leq 1$. How can I choose the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ so that I've got a) almost sure convergence and b) convergence in probability? I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: Why not try something simple like assume $a_n\rightarrow 0$ or $b_n\rightarrow 0$. Can you analyze one of these cases? Or even easier, make the sequences constant...(which seems to make this question trivial).

Comment: I don't get along with it. I'm trying to show it by the Kolmogorov's three-series theorem. But the problem is that this is only  valid for series...

Comment: The 3-series theorem seems like heavy-lifting for a simple problem.  Isn't it trivial that, if $a_n=b_n=1$ for all $n$, then $X_n = |X|$ for all $n$ and so all types of convergence are immediate?  Or, if you specifically want convergence to 0, just do as I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: @Thesinus Any sequence of real numbers may be written as a series and vice versa.

Comment: I get it, thanks! Am I right in saying that this also converges in mean as $X$ is a normal distribution on $[0,1]$?